# Javascript change value inside class

Tags: javascript, replace

I am using a video carousel to browse through videos and would like the current video to auto play.

All the videos are defaulted to "autoplay=false". What I am looking for is; if the class="current" then "autoplay=true"

```
  <li class="NOT-current">
    <object data="http://view.vzaar.com/12345" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="showplaybutton=rollover&amp;border=none&amp;autoplay=flase" />
    </object>
  </li>

  <li class="current">
    <object data="http://view.vzaar.com/12345" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="showplaybutton=rollover&amp;border=none&amp;autoplay=TRUE" />
    </object>
  </li>

  <li class="NOT-current">
    <object data="http://view.vzaar.com/12345" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="showplaybutton=rollover&amp;border=none&amp;autoplay=false" />
    </object>
  </li>
```

I know there must be a very simple line of js to change this, maybe using find and replace, but I cant figure it out

Comment: What js framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about pure js, but you could try something like that with jQuery :

```
var object = $(".current").find("object");
object.children().attr("value", "showplaybutton=rollover&amp;border=none&amp;autoplay=TRUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some javascript you are using to change the class to current video object there only add a line  `$(videoObject).play();` to play the video

Comment: It seems to be the best solution, I didn't think about that ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you could try this:

```
$("li.current object").context.play();
```